# OperaDriver not working

Tags: c#, opera, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Using Selenium Grid2 and RemoteWebDriver in an MSTest class, I am struggling to get OperaDriver working.

I create the Selenium hub and Opera node by running the following commands in CMD:

```
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.30.0.jar -role hub
start java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.30.0.jar -role node -port 7001 -browser "browserName=opera,version=11.62,maxInstances=5,platform=WINDOWS" -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

And this works fine, I can the see the registered node when I view my hub in a browser.

But I get an exception whenever I try to create a new `WebDriver` in my C# test class:

```
DesiredCapabilities operaCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Opera();
operaCapabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "opera");
operaCapabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "WINDOWS");
operaCapabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "11.62");
operaCapabilities.SetCapability("opera.binary", "C:\\Program Files\\Opera\\opera.exe");
operaCapabilities.SetCapability("opera.port", 7001);
RemoteWebDriver operaDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(operaCapabilities);
```

Actually I get two different exceptions - the first time after creating the hub and node in Selenium I get this:

> Could not find a platform that supports bundled launchers, please set
>   it manually
>
> Build info: version: '2.30.0', revision: 'dc1ef9c', time: '2013-02-19
>   00:15:27'
>
> System info: os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.2',
>   java.version: '1.7.0_15'
>
> Driver info: driver.version: OperaDriver

And everytime after that I get the following error:

> Could not initialize class
>   com.opera.core.systems.runner.launcher.OperaLauncherRunner

I am using `Selenium-standalone-2.30.0`.

I was using Opera version 12.14 but downgraded to 11.62 after I saw a list of compatible versions on the [OperaDriver wiki page](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/OperaDriver) but the errors remain the same.

I have tried initialising the RemoteWebDriver with and without the capabilities above and get the same result every time.

Does anyone know what the problem is here and how to get a RemoteWebDriver working with Opera in this way?

**Edit**: Could it be that the platform for `Opera version 12.14` reads as `'WINDOWS 8'`, and version `11.62` reads as `"WIN32"` when I open the `Opera` browser and view `Help => About`? As I am specifying the platform as `WINDOWS` in the node and `RemoteWebDriver`. If I try to specify WINDOWS 8 as the platform for the RemoteWebDriver an new exception is thrown where it can't find matching enum:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant
>   org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS 8

**Edit2**: For some reason `CurrentPlatform` is returning `Vista` for me, even though I am running `Windows8`.

```
Platform platform = Platform.CurrentPlatform;
```

And I also noticed that the [`OperaDriver` source code](https://github.com/operasoftware/operadriver/blob/master/src/com/opera/core/systems/runner/launcher/OperaLauncherRunner.java) checks for 'VISTA' in uppercase whereas the Platform in C# reads as 'Vista'.

Could this be causing the problem?

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? I have the same error.

Comment: not yet, I have noticed that a newer version of Selenium standalone has been released since I posted this question but haven't had the chance to test if it has been resolved yet

Comment: I did the test usig the last one :( - 2.31.0.

Answer (score 3):

I've been suffering from this problem as well and thanks to the hint from eviltester I was able to solve the issue by using the following command line to start the selenium server:

```
java -Dos.name=windows -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar
```

The use of `-Dos.name=windows` is the equivalent of `System.setProperty("os.name", "windows")` and will allow your C# selenium code to work for the Opera browser.

Comment: thanks I had the same error for IE11 and this solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I saw this when running in Java. In debug mode it looked like a possible omission in OperaLauncherRunner.java launcherNameForOS does not cater for the WIN8 enum returned by Platform.getCurrent().

In Java I fudged it by setting the system property "os.name" to "windows" before creating a new OperaDriver. This forced the Platform.getCurrent to return XP which the opera launcher was happy with.

So in java I just used this hack:

```
System.setProperty("os.name","windows");
driver = new OperaDriver();
```